# how to add a raw in a tableview with two deferent cells

Tags: ios, swift, append, tableview, cell

what I did  :

I have two textfield (name - link ) , I want the user when he fill the textfields and press Add button , the new data is input to the tableview ..

I did that!!

my goal is :

when I press the Add button I just can to target one cell how can I add the two data (link - name )

in this code

```
 @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {


    data.append("\(link.text!)")
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: data.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

how can I set link.text and name.text together

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
   cell.cell4Name.text = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.cell4Link.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {


    data.append("\(link.text!)")
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: data.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define 2 arrays for the names and links.

```
var names = [String]()
var links = [STring]()
```

then change *add* method to this:

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    names.append("\(nameTextField.text!)")
    links.append("\(linkTextField.text!)")
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

also you should do some changes in *tableView* codes

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count //or links.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.cell4Name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.cell4Link.text = links[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```